Error: AppwriteException: Network request failed using local Appwrite Installation
Because of the rate limit of the cloud version of Appwrite i installed and have set up Appwrite locally. Everything worked and i implemented the project structure like in the cloud. Now when i try to open a connection to my local appwrite it says [Error: AppwriteException: Network request failed].
I am using Appwrite for my React Native App.
I dont know why and i also dont find a more detailled error message. The endpoint is correct with http://localhost/v1 and everything else is the same except for the IDs from the Project, Storage, Database, etc..

I found out what the Problem is:
I use Expo Go on my Phone to simulate the App. I think the cause is that the App tries to connect to the local appwrite but on my Phone, that of course does not exist there.
When i open the App in the web on my PC it works.
I will post here again if i find a workaround or fix for that.
